# Three.js Fast way to recover a 3d Object Possible request?

Tags: three.js

I have a mesh, its 'id' is 40 (for example).
I can get the id property from object3D.

Now ... I have an id. 
I have the scene.children array. I have to find the id inside this array. (for loop)

mmm Wouldn't it be better to have a 'map' array ? That is:

Map[id] = index_n  of children array (so I could get the object faster)

Could this be a request?

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you elaborate on the reason you have an ID as opposed to (a reference to) the Object3D itself?

Comment: @Paul-Jan I have this ID in order to access to the object without pick it. (The id is given by Three.js)

Comment: Why not just create that map as you are creating the scene yourself? Few people will need a feature like this really. And by the way, there is the `.traverse()` method on any `Object3D` (including the scene) to iterate through.